# Best Way to register Custom Content Element to Type-Dropdown

Tags: configuration, typo3

What is the best way to add a content element to the "Type" dropdown?

In the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/AddingYourOwnContentElements/Index.html#configuration-tca-overrides-tt-content-php) only the function `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPlugin` is recommended.

With this function, I can't determine the position of the item in the "Type" dropdown.

But with the function `addTcaSelectItem` i can determine the position of the element.

Have I overlooked something? Is there a reason why `addPlugin` is recommended and not `addTcaSelectItem`?

**Example Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php**

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPlugin(
   array(
      'LLL:EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/Tca.xlf:yourextensionkey_newcontentelement',
      'yourextensionkey_newcontentelement',
      'EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Public/Icons/ContentElements/yourextensionkey_newcontentelement.svg'
   ),
   'CType',
   'your_extension_key'
);
```

With Position after textmedia-element

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
    'tt_content',
    'CType',
    [
        'LLL:EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/Tca.xlf:yourextensionkey_newcontentelement',
        'yourextensionkey_newcontentelement',
        'EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Public/Icons/ContentElements/yourextensionkey_newcontentelement.svg'
    ],
    'textmedia',
    'after'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a different between content element types and plugins in TYPO3.

Registered plugins will not be shown/available separately in content element type selector. Each registered plugin is only available as a sub-selection of content element type `plugin` (`list`).

I guess you wish to add your own new content element and not an element of type plugin. Then you may have a look at EXT:bootstrap_package from Benjamin Kott, which contains a best practice for such usecase.

For example TYPO3 TCA configuration below for TYPO3 8.7 and 9.5

- adds a custom content element `newcontentelement`
- assigns an icon identifier `content-yourextensionkey-newcontentelement` which must registered in `ext_localconf.php`
- and configures fields for editors in backend (`showitem`)

*EXT:your_extension_key/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php*

```
// Add 'newcontentelement' to tt_content.CType selector list
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
    'tt_content',
    'CType',
    [
        'New content element', # Use localization 'LLL:EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/Backend.xlf:content_element.newcontentelement',
        'newcontentelement',
        'content-yourextensionkey-newcontentelement'
    ],
    '--div--',
    'after'
);
// Assign Icon for tt_content.CType 'newcontentelement'
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['ctrl']['typeicon_classes']['newcontentelement'] = 'content-yourextensionkey-newcontentelement';
// Configure content element type 'newcontentelement'
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['newcontentelement']['showitem'] = '
    --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general,
        --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
        --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.headers;headers,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.appearance,
        --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.frames;frames,
        --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.appearanceLinks;appearanceLinks,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:language,
        --palette--;;language,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:access,
        --palette--;;hidden,
        --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;access,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:categories,
        categories,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:notes,
        rowDescription,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:extended,
';
```

You need to adopt the `showitem` array for your requirements to enable content element fields in backend for editors.

Add your customised content element icon under `EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Public/Icons` called fx `mimetypes-x-content-newcontentelement.svg`

*EXT:your_extension_key/ext_localconf.php*

```
// Register Icons
$iconRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry::class);
$iconRegistry->registerIcon(
    'content-yourextensionkey-newcontentelement',
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\SvgIconProvider::class,
    ['source' => 'EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Public/Icons/mimetypes-x-content-newcontentelement.svg']
);
```

You may wish to provide your new content element in the wizard for creating new content elements.
Add configuration below to your page configuration (`pageTSConfig`):

```
mod.wizards {
    newContentElement {
        wizardItems {
            special {
                elements {
                    newcontentelement {
                        icon = EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Public/Icons/mimetypes-x-content-newcontentelement.svg
                        title = LLL:EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/Backend.xlf:content_element.newcontentelement
                        description = LLL:EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/Backend.xlf:content_element.newcontentelement.description
                        tt_content_defValues {
                            CType = newcontentelement
                        }
                    }
                }
                show = *
            }
        }
    }
}
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.special.show := addToList(newcontentelement)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer but i know how to create a custom CE. With my question i want to find out why in the documentation function addPlugin is recommended to register the new elment to the Type-dropdown and not function addTcaSelectItem where you can even can determine the order.

Comment: Just feel free to improve the documentation https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/edit/master/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Documentation/AddingYourOwnContentElements/Index.rst

Comment: addPlugin can add items to a field determined by the second parameter, which defaults to "list-type" - still it can do the same for any other field that's holding items similar to "list_type". So IMHO the name of the method is misleading, while the documentation is correct.